# Protect Arduino components from ESD damage from external input

Tags: arduino, esd, over-voltage-protection, diode-clamp, electrostatic

I have an Arduino Due project that senses voltages through an ADC (ADS1115). The ADS1115 voltage sensor inputs will have intermittent connections. I have already fried my compass module by ESD and am trying to prevent this in the future.

The ADS passes through a level shifter to bring voltages down to 3.3 V communication with the 3.3 V Arduino Due prototype board. The voltages I'm measuring with the ADS need to be very precise and I've found that trying to input protect directly at the ADS1115 throws off voltage readings.

I'm thinking the next best option is to make the ADS essentially disposable (they're cheap) and to protect the other components from ESD behind the ADS1115 (Arduino/level shifter/compass). The project is protected by a plastic enclosure from any user touch/ESD source EXCEPT at the ADS1115 voltage measuring inputs.

I've read that you can protect from ESD with TVS diode clamps similar to [this USB-C protection diagram](https://blog.semtech.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Figure-2-USB-Type-C.png?width=900&name=Figure-2-USB-Type-C.png). If I install TVS diode clamps between the battery/Arduino GND and the 5 V/SCL/SDA connections (A/B/C in the diagram), will this prevent ESD damage to the Arduino/level shifter/compass?

[image: Wiring schematic]

Comment: Adding TVS diodes can help but might distort the signal beyond usefulness.  What are the voltages you are reading?  What is their input impedance?  Frequencies of interest?  Magnitude?

Comment: The voltages I'm reading with the ADS1115 are DC voltages within the range of the ADS capabilities (+/-5V). I was thinking that if I added clamp diodes on the SDA/SCL/5V wires as shown in my diagram then it wouldn't interfere with the ADS readings because the diode clamps are only protecting the I2C communication and the 5V supply. The intention is to sacrifice the ADS1115 in the event of an ESD while the other components would be spared. Or maybe there's a better way to protect this while not disrupting the ADS1115 accuracy.

Comment: I2C isn't especially picky, so I think TVS diodes on the data lines could be worth a try.  I2C wasn't really designed to go off-board (though it does all the time, me = guilty), so finding suitable TVS diodes might not be as easy as for e.g. CAN bus but general purpose ones would probably work.  The 400 pF bus limit is about 10x what a GP TVS diode is so that probably isn't something to worry about here.  Edit: found this, which might come in handy: https://www.semtech.com/uploads/common/PB-SEMTECH-TVS-I2C-BUS.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the leads. I think something like this would work:
https://www.ti.com/product/ISO1640-Q1

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.  A common PCB is required, or a metal enclosure with protection wired with respect to it (it will usually be wired to circuit GND as well), at the point of entry.

The reason is because you have considerable poorly- or un-coupled wires between the main board and the peripherals.  An ESD strike to an input induces current not just in the immediate pin, but that current spreads out between each connected board in turn, until the pulse's charge is equalized between everything.  (This in fact happens at the speed of light, because ESD has a rise time under 5ns and the wave really does spread out in real time.  There can be voltage drops of ~kV across 10cm's of wire!)

You need a plane or shield to sink that current to, so that current can spread out around its exterior, like a wave crashing around a lighthouse.  Like a lighthouse, the shield needs to wrap around or at least mostly cover the stuff being shielded.

The cheapest solution is to use a solid ground plane inside one PCB.  This works well enough: as the ESD current mostly flows around the perimeter, components and traces on the outer layers are mostly shielded from it, though they can still get disturbed by electric field along the surface (which is mostly shunted to plane just under the surface, but a fraction still goes into traces/etc.).

So, you can take the schematics from everything, put it on one board, and build that, with ESD protection on external connecting lines only; or take what you have and put it in a metal enclosure, or at least tacked down to a metal plate with grounding straps tying each board's ground plane to it, and ESD protection on all the outside connecting wires on a new board at the edge of the plate.  (Basically making your own *un*printed circuit board on a ground plane.)

It would also be an option to use shielded cables between boards -- extending the shield from each board over the wires themselves -- but as the boards do not have shielded connectors, this will be nontrivial, if it's possible at all.  (It's not enough to use e.g. coax to the connectors as-is, because that leaves unshielded length.  Yes, even just 1-2cm of unshielded length matters!)

Comment: What about using an i2C bus buffer between the voltage sensor and the MCU/level converter? https://www.ti.com/product/ISO1640-Q1